# Use of priors on hyper-parameters with SVGP model

Tags: gpflow

I wanted to use priors on hyper-parameters as in (https://gpflow.readthedocs.io/en/develop/notebooks/advanced/mcmc.html) but with an SVGP model.

Following the steps of example 1, I got an error when I run de run_chain_fn :

> TypeError: maximum_log_likelihood_objective() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'

Contrary to GPR or SGPMC, the data are not an attribut of the model, they are included as external parameter.

To avoid that problem I modified slightly SVGP class to include data as parameter (I don't care with mini-batching for now)

```
class SVGP_with_data(gpflow.models.SVGP):
"""This model is a tiny variation of classical SVGP. It just includes the data as an optionnal 
    parameter of the model, since they are necessary of MCMC sampling"""

def __init__(self,data,**kwargs):
    super().__init__(**kwargs)
    self.data = data
    
def maximum_log_likelihood_objective(self,_=None):
    return self.elbo(self.data)     #here we don't care about mini-batching
```

It seems to work well.

I couldn't find code example of SVGP with priors on hyper-parameters. Is their a more standard way to deel with this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SVGP` is a GPflow model for a *variational* approximation. Using MCMC on the *q(u)* distribution parameterised by `q_mu` and `q_sqrt` doesn't make sense (if you want to do MCMC on *q(u)* in a sparse approximation, use `SGPMC`).

You can still put (hyper)priors on the hyperparameters in the `SVGP` model; gradient-based optimisation will then lead to the maximum a-posteriori (MAP) point estimate (as opposed to pure maximum likelihood).

Comment: In fact I am not interested in MCMC on **q(u)**, I have a prior mean function and I wanted posterior distribution of the coefficients and take into account their uncertainty in the prediction.  I wanted to add priors on these coefficients, without having to change of variational approximation with SGPMC. But MCMC doesn't seem to work with SVGP (because data are not included in the model, see above), which seems strange...

Comment: In any case, I will try SGPMC too.

Comment: q(u) is (implicitly) a function of the kernel hyperparameters, so whenever you change the hyperparameters, you have to also update q(u). So what you _could_ do (in principle; this is probably a lot of hassle both computationally and code-wise) is to do a _single_ step of MCMC on the kernel hyperparameters, then optimise q(u) to convergence, then do another step of MCMC.

Comment: You can also do variational inference on your mean function coefficients (requires a bit more handcrafted model building).

Comment: I think we can conclude that if we are interested in posterior distributions of hyperparameters for a sparse model, the simplest thing to do is to use SGPMC which is designed for that.